# Google visualization datatable multi pivoting

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, google-visualization

Here is a google visualization data table which is in the following format

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
data.addColumn('string', 'Col2');
data.addColumn('string', 'Col3');
data.addColumn('number', 'Col4');
 data.addRows([
     ['Name1', 'foo', 'A', 2],
     ['Name1', 'foo', 'B', 5],
     ['Name1', 'bar', 'A', 3],
     ['Name1', 'bar', 'B', 4],
     ['Name2', 'foo', 'A', 4],
     ['Name2', 'foo', 'B', 8],
     ['Name2', 'bar', 'A', 1],
     ['Name2', 'bar', 'B', 5]
    ]);
```

which is dynamically generating from the server. Is it possible to pivot the above data table in the format given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z9AXL/1/).

**EDIT:** By referring [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/HkjDe/) by asgallant, I managed to get one level of pivoting which is given here: http://jsfiddle.net/Z9AXL/2/

Comment: You can pivot on as many columns as you want, eg: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/Z9AXL/3/.  You cannot get the multi-level header row from your example, however.

Comment: Is there any hack with jquery to format header by changing its style?

Comment: You could try adding another row to the Table (it's just an HTML table) with appropriate classes for styling, and changing `rowspan` and `colspan` properties on the cells.  There are a bunch of issues that could crop up (breaking the sort interactivity of the column headers, breaking the fixed header on scrollable tables, maybe more), but its technically doable.